# Adding days and time to a timestamp in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have 3 fields in my table: `start_time: TIMESTAMP`, `days_prior: INT`, and `time_open: TIME`. I want to retrieve from this the value of start_time - days, set the time portion of the result to `00:00:00` and then add the time to that.

That is, the original timestamp might be something like '2013-05-02 14:57:00' and days is 1, time is '09:30:00' and I want to return '2013-05-01 09:30:00'.

I realize that this can be done by splitting out the date portion of the timestamp, and then concatenating it with the time. However, if I wanted to use the result in the same query as part of my where statement, then I would need the result of the concatenation to be a timestamp as well.

My query, ideally, would look something like the following:

```
SELECT
    t1.id, 
    t1.start_time,
    CONCAT(DATE_SUB(DATE(t1.start_time), INTERVAL t2.days_prior DAY), ' ', t2.time_open) 
FROM
    t1, t2
WHERE
    t1.t2_id = t2.id
```

This, however, is producing results looking like:

```
1, 2012-10-30 18:00:00, 323031322d31302d33302030393a30303a3030
```

Comment: works good for me.. Can you populate the actual data using [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: how odd. works ok for me there as well, but on my local db, it does not....

Comment: a little more debugging - it appears that the issue is related to the concat, because I checked each value going into that function, and each appears to be correct.

Comment: The column names in your query do not match the column names in the partial schema you provided. Please update them.

Comment: updated accordingly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to avoid the string operation CONCAT when dealing with dates and times. There are proper [date and time func](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) to handle this instead.

Try if this works for you. It gives a real datetime so if you need to format it for presentation you need to add that.

```
SELECT
    t1.id, 
    t1.start_time,
    MAKEDATE(YEAR(t1.start_time), DAYOFYEAR(t1.start_time)) - INTERVAL t2.days_prior DAY + INTERVAL t.2time_open HOUR_SECOND
FROM
    t1, t2
WHERE
    t1.t2_id = t2.id
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/50a5e/15)

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm. Still wondering why my version produces what looks like garbage, but more important to me at the moment is to have a working version.